# WCF + Unit test cases

Tags: wcf, debugging, testcase

This seems to be a weird issue, I had solution with a WCF Service and Unit Test Project.

In Unit test, I had some testcases which will step into WCF service. When I start the service, and go into Test-case (Test explorer) all test-cases are disabled, and in Test => all Debug / RunAll tests all options are disabled.  So I am not able to debug testcases when WCF Service is running this is the issue. I am using VS2013 Ultimate with Update3 installed.

I am rightclicking on WCF Service debug start new instance, then go into Test-case (Test-explorer) when I right click on test-case all options are disabled and so is in Test menu.

Comment: I am a little bit confused about what is your question. You have a problem that you can not test your project while the project is running? That is not possible if I am not mistaken. You can either run a unit test or you can run a  project (service).

Comment: Sorry, I want to run a unit test in project. This unit test will call wcf operation contract. I am running wcf service through iisexpress. without service running how the testcase will execute.

Comment: Well you can either write a robust integration test, that will launch the service itself or use technique called "mocking".

Comment: this question has been asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2790901/debugging-visual-studio-2010-unit-test-and-wcf-service-in-one-ide-instance?s=3e5cefa3a3b146cbb2e71ba4644d50a6